# Save default values in Yii2 not working

Tags: yii2, yii2-basic-app, scenarios, yii2-model

I want to save the this following datetime while update or create so I wrote this in rules()

```
['createdon','default','value'=>date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),'on'=>'insert' ],
['updatedon','default','value'=>date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),'on'=>'update' ],
```

and I declare scenario in create and update functions as

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new JobFunctionRole();
    $model->scenario = 'insert';
....
....
}
public function actionUpdate($id)
{
    $model = $this->findModel($id);
    $model->scenario = 'update';
    ...
    ...
}
```

While create datetime stores perfectly.but in update its not stores.Whats the issue??Anybody?

Comment: Is `updatedon` empty before update ? And you could use `yii\behaviors\TimestampBehavior` for this.

Comment: but how insert works correctly?

Answer (score 1):

These are validators for user input. You probably are looking for `TimestampBehavior`:
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-behaviors-timestampbehavior.html

The `TimestampBehavior` config should be added to an `ActiveRecord` model. Not the controller.

Comment: I added this in my controller ` [
                'class' => TimestampBehavior::className(),
                'createdAtAttribute' => 'createdon',
                'updatedAtAttribute' => 'updatedon',
                'value' => new Expression('NOW()'),
            ],' But not helps

Comment: @Jackhad. It should have `int` datatype in mysql.

Comment: @Jackhad it should be added to the model, not the controller... Just like the docs says.

Comment: no its datetime datatype for me..Any configs for that?

Comment: @ddinchev its working fine but ..When I use the model for REST APi then it returns like `"updatedon": {
        "expression": "NOW()",
        "params": []
    }' I dont want user to see this.any idea?

Comment: ok I got it ,we can use ` date("Y-m-d H:i:s") ` directly. instead of ` new Expression('NOW()') `.Thanks!Hope this would help someone.

Comment: Be aware that using `new Expression('NOW()')` is a MySQL function that internally sets the datetime to the current datetime of the MySQL server. While PHP's `date` function could be setting a date in different timezone. Also, if the answer helped you achieve your goal - please accept it.

Answer (score 1):

You directly use _form

```
 <?= $form->field($model, 'createdon')->hiddenInput('value'=>date("Y-m-d")])->label(false) ?>
```